# How can i draw the spring motion in the gif file in golang?

Tags: go

[Gif file that i have to make](https://hyosangkang.notion.site/image/https%3A%2F%2Fs3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com%2Fsecure.notion-static.com%2F9f8492fa-bd42-4cb2-a3b7-4f77da365cc3%2Fgraph.gif?table=block&id=cbd151ac-549f-46af-9d0c-100d6456b3dc&spaceId=929754e5-3c74-481d-bc9d-233fe96a15bb&userId=&cache=v2)

This gif file is what i have to make.
I draw a mass circle like this

```
func (s *SpSim) circleXY(l, i int) [2]int {
    r := s.Ginfo.CR
    xi := int(float64(r) * math.Cos(2*math.Pi*float64(i)/100))
    xi += s.Ginfo.Pad + s.Ginfo.SprWidth/2
    yi := int(float64(r) * math.Sin(2*math.Pi*float64(i)/100))
    yi += l
    return [2]int{xi, yi}
}
```

but I can't think how to draw the spring part for the gif file.
How can I make a spring attached to the ceiling and the mass?
I'm trying to make a function that draws the spring like this

```
func (s *SpSim) addSpring(c *image.Paletted, count int) {

}
```

but I can't fill the function TT

Comment: What have you tried? What issues did you run into? Can you show your code attempting to solve this?

Comment: I have no idea how to draw the spring

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. People here can help if you have a problem you cannot fix - but cannot be expected to write the solution for you.

Comment: I dont want people to fill my code. I just want some several ideas for drawing the spring